# Keyboard and touchpad do not work after upgrade

Tags: unity, 11.04, keyboard, eeepc

Today I made an update of my ubuntu 11.04 installation. After rebooting the keyboard and touchpad of my asus eeepc do not work anymore. I can only login with the onscreen keyboard. Seems to be a unity problem. Never had this problem before.
How can I make my keyboard work again?

After upgrading I also run the following command:
sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: start your computer with recovery mode (start holdig SHIFT **BEFORE** the boot, and it will display first the grub menu, select the 2nd entry: "Ubuntu, ... Linux, ... <kernel info> [Recovery mode]") ... then select root shell, and try a system upgrade... will it help?

Comment: This worked perfectly. It downloaded several packages and after rebooting everything worked as before. During my first installation it said, that several packages were "Kept-back", do you know what that means?
Please add a response for your comment, so I can mark this question as solved.

Comment: Yes, maybe I know, but I have to know what packages... if they was kernel updates, you used: `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and that doesn't mention kernel things. If you run: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, it will mention all updates. *(I'll post an answer if you like :))*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have some problems because of uninstalled packages...

To repair that problem, try:

1. **Start Ubuntu in recovery mode** - hold SHIFT key **before** the system boots, and it will display Grub bootloader. Select the last version of the kernel with the *[recovery]* in the end of the name.
   [image: grub menu]
2. **Select the root shell option**
   [image: recovery mode]
3. **Try to upgrade your system** - if there are problems (& errors), post them here... The other way, to **select dpkg** option - that may fix some other problems.
4. **Reboot** - type `exit` to jump back to recovery menu, then there select **resume** boot option.

Comment: selecting the **dpkg** option worked for me.

Comment: Had this problem with 12.04. Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. You are a gentleman and a scholar.