# Keyboard and touch-pad stopped working after shutting down the computer while it was installing updates

Tags: 10.10, package-management, keyboard, touchpad

When I boot my notebook, the touch-pad and the keyboard don't respond. 
The last thing I did before shutting down was killing the terminal that was running a sudo apt-get install because I had to go.

I tried to follow the [Start Ubuntu in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34295/keyboard-and-touchpad-do-not-work-after-upgrade)

but the second screen (Select the root shell option ) does not appear in my computer, it runs some process and then it freezes

I have the ubuntu liveCD and I can mount my hard drive from there but I'm not sure what commands to run from there.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to *chroot* into your system from the live CD and continue the upgrade.

1. Run the live CD and start a `gnome-terminal` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> → `gnome-terminal`).
2. Issue the following command to mount your system (change **sda1** to whatever your system partition name is - the output of the command `fdisk -l` should give you an idea):

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ubuntu
   ```
3. You need to bind a couple of local directories to the chroot environment:

   ```
   for i in proc sys dev; do sudo mount --bind /$i /mnt/ubuntu/$i; done
   ```
4. Enable DNS resolving in the chroot environment (should give you internet access):

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/ubuntu/etc/resolv.conf
   ```
5. Now it's time to get into your broken system (note, that you will be the almighty root user in the system, so be careful what you do):

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt/ubuntu
   ```
6. Try to continue the update:

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get upgrade
   ```

   You'll maybe told to also try

   ```
   apt-get -f install
   ```

   If that fails you can also try to continue the configuration of unpacked packages:

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```
7. After you've tampered with the system, you type `exit` to leave your system and then do the above steps in reverse order:

   ```
   sudo rm /mnt/ubuntu/etc/resolv.conf
   sudo umount /mnt/ubuntu/dev
   sudo umount /mnt/ubuntu/sys
   sudo umount /mnt/ubuntu/proc
   sudo umount /mnt/ubuntu
   ```
8. Reboot without the CD and hope for the best.

Comment: Running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` will likely fail since the previous upgrade process is incomplete. Running `dpkg --configure -a` will complete upgrade.

Comment: Good point, added to the answer.