# Uninstalled python package, now the system is broken

Tags: 10.10

While trying to free some space by unistalling some useless applications, I accidently have choosen the python file to be unistalled, then something wrong happens, most of programs of Ubuntu 10.10 were unistalled and much worse, the laptop was not responding.

I tried to restart, then I had the bad surprise: and error message saying that the graphic interface is not available anymore, i can access in a textual mode, do you think that i can get back my installation without reinstalling all the OS?

Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 6):

- To reinstall, run this from the command line (you said you can still access 'text mode'):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard ubuntu-desktop
  ```

  This should get your base setup working again, but I cannot say if any programs you manually installed will still be there as `python` is a critical package as you now know*.
- If this does not work, you can try to recover your system with a live CD. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40457/keyboard-and-touch-pad-stopped-working-after-shutting-down-the-computer-while-it/42062#42062) about how to access your broken system from a live CD via *chroot*.

  At point 6 you would need to reinstall all the things that were removed. As I don't know the current state of your broken system, you may or may not need to run the commands from the linked answer. Then, like above, run:

  ```
  apt-get install ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard ubuntu-desktop
  ```

*) If you didn't choose to also delete configuration files, you might be able to easily reinstall the software via Synaptic: select the *Not installed (residual config)* item in the left pane, then select the software in the right pane for reinstallation:

[image]

Comment: well unfortunately i tried both and it didn't work!!!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly didn't work? What were the errors you got?

Comment: hi, again when i run the first command sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard ubuntu-desktop , i got the error message : E: impossible to get http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/totem .....
and when i tried to use the second method (live CD) i had same kind of message, i think that the problem is in the sources.list file, but i don't know how to add a link in the sources.file while i have only access to the command line.

Comment: @wafadz Have you been connected to the internet when trying the live CD?

Comment: @htorque, First, thanks for you kind help. I couldn't get back my installation I downloaded an ISO image of ubuntu 11.04 (32 bits),and I have burnt the ISO
using the "burn as image" option. 11.04 64bit didn't work properly even though I have a 64bit CPU. I also had some trouble to configure my ethernet card under 10.04 but when I installed the version 11.04 32 bits, it worked and it is really a stable and I could reinstall my software and it is working properly.