# Removed Kernel by mistake

Tags: 11.04, kernel, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

I was trying to remove some older versions of my kernel to decrease the GRUB menu size. And I removed even the newer ones by mistake and did `sudo update-grub`. Now, I get grub menu but have no linux options. Can someone please help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

You'd need to start a live CD, access your installation and install the kernel again.

Look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40457/keyboard-and-touch-pad-stopped-working-after-shutting-down-the-computer-while-it/42062#42062) about how to access your installation via *chroot*. Ignore step 6 and do this instead:

```
apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic
```