# Boot fail after update kernel in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

When I want to install with this command `sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.14.24-031424-generic_3.14.24-031424.201411141736_amd64.deb` I got follow error:

```
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.14.24-031424-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.14.24-031424-generic (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.14.24-031424-generic
```

After restart I got this error:

```
Initialize variable space ...
Starting cmain() ... (hd0,0)
[Multibot-kludge, loaddaddr=0x100000, text-adn-data=0x6315, bss=0x0, entry=0x100990]
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grab rescue>
```

How can I boot again?
Pleas help me!!

**UPDATE 1**

This file is result of boot-repair package: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9143905/
http://textuploader.com/ow4p

**UPDATE 2**

When I want to purge previous grub and install new one with boot-repair in live cd, got this error:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: unknown filesystem.
```

**UPDATE 3**

When I run this command: `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`
I got this output:
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: unknown filesystem.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find root device after latest kernel upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361886/cannot-find-root-device-after-latest-kernel-upgrade)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Excuse me, Can I solve this problem or reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: if reinstall is not a problem to you then do it. from next time never upgrade kernel(never experiment with you system). dont change your system, just do installation which is safe. if  you cant reinstall then try above method and tell me, whether it worked or not

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Thanks, I'd try it, It's not working for me, Updates in question is result of boot-repair app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use boot repair burn it as image on cd and leave it .
it will repair every thing.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/
after that u can boot ubuntu again.

Comment: Thanks, You don't have any idea to solve this error?

Comment: try synaptic and remove grub then use boot repair it will fix grub and restart.try it

Comment: @Daniyal you should try using boot repair. on this page there is a tutorial how to do it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

here are some methods that will help you to recover system if kernel is remove by mistake

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/28100/294611
2. https://askubuntu.com/a/46696/294611
3. https://askubuntu.com/a/100953/294611

all three answers above are different ways to do the same thing, try atleast one(since all are same). First read all the answers then try the method you understand.