# How can I find most stable and newest kernel edition for Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel

I want to choose a newest and most stable version Linux kernel for Ubuntu.
Is it newest longterm version in http://kernel.org version(and download equivalent version in http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline)?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

:-) *The most stable* **is not the newest**

Actually, both are mutually exclusive...  And as you have another question open with [Boot fail after update kernel in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551788/boot-fail-after-update-kernel-in-ubuntu-14-04), I would stay with the standard...

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ uname -r
3.13.0-34-generic

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: The truth is not always easy.