# kubuntu 15.10 - Each time I try to install something I get the same dependency errors but the package seems to install OK

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, dependencies

I get the following every time I try to install anything. It always seems to install OK but I'd rather not get the errors, what am I supposed to do to fix this? All I'd like to know really is where to start looking, I'd like a push in the right direction rather than a complete solution.

Or if anyone could just point me to the correct link? I've spent hours looking for it and not found anything that really applies to me.

My guess is that I should look at the repositories?

```
linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2

linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

linux-image-generic
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

linux-generic
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

linux-signed-image-4.2.0-35-generic
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

linux-signed-image-generic
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

linux-signed-generic
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

initramfs-tools
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you post the complete output and the commands you experienced the problems with? Output of "sudo df -h" would be interesting to see if theres enough space - maybe the boot partition is out of space.

Comment: There are a few solutions if you lookup the errors "initramfs-tools
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1"  && "subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2"  see this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/517857/dpkg-error-processing-package-linux-image-generic-configure-dependency-pro  && this:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109698/dpkg-dependency-problems-prevent-configuration-of-initramfs-tools

Comment: I'm using kbuntu Discover...not exactly sure where to look for the complete output. If I knew that it's quite possible that you're right. Is there somewhere I need to look....I'm guessing Discover is just a nice interface to dpkg anyway...system log?

Comment: menu -> system -> konsole

Comment: Scrub that...guess what?

gzip: stdout: No space left on device

E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1

update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic with 1.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Grrr! Not sure why my fmtg is all up the spout but I think you'll get the gist. I assume, since there always used to be enough space in my boot dir that I need to do some housekeeping? Any suggestions for best option?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot or google the output / parts in ""  to find another solution  - anyways - the link should do - maybe the synaptic GUI option answer is more easy for you

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help - my boot partition is now at 44% and miracle of miracles, it still boots. That is always my worry when mucking about with boot partitions, I've had many bad experiences! Supplemental question...can I/should I make my boot partition bigger? I know the answer already...it's working, leave it alone, but I was just wondering. I still think I have too many kernels in there, is uname -a the only one I need?

Comment: I wrote an answer for better understanding and fast problem solving for others (bundled information to spare time going through all this :) )

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the above question is/was that **old kernels filled up the boot partition**. [How do I resize my /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition)

Basic command to check free space on your mounted partitions: `sudo df -h`

> Below information is an extremely shortened version of:  [How do I
>   remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)
>
> The basic commands in this situation:
>
> `uname -r` - check which kernel is in use
>
> `sudo apt-get autoremove` - remove old kernel
>
> A normal kernel upgrade should work flawlessly as follows:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove
> ```

If for any reason something goes wrong during a kernel upgrade may read this:
[How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels/28100#28100)
and eventually this: [Removed Kernel by mistake [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46687/removed-kernel-by-mistake/46696#46696) && [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)